# Why does Realm suggest that List<T> properties be declared using "let"?

Tags: swift, realm

Realm's documentation on [to-many relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships) declares its `List<Dog>` property using `let`:

```
class Person: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

Why is this `List<T>` property declared using `let` when other Realm property types are declared using `dynamic var`?

Comment: Same logic applies to `RealmOptional`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<T>` properties should be declared using `let` as Realm is unable to intercept assignment to these properties. Assigning to `List<T>` properties won't result in your changes being persisted to the Realm file. By declaring the property using `let` rather than `var` you enlist the Swift compiler to detect code that won't do what you intend.

Instead of assigning to `List<T>` properties you should *mutate* the existing value of the property via the methods that are part of the [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceablecollection) protocol to which `List<T>` conforms.

For instance, to add a new dog:

```
person.dogs.append(lassie)
```

Or to replace the existing dogs:

```
person.dogs.replaceSubrange(0..<person.dogs.count, with: [fido, spot])
```

---

#### Why?

Realm model classes automatically implement getters and setters for your persisted properties that access the underlying database data. In order to provide these getters and setters, your properties must be declared with the `dynamic` modifier. This modifier asks Swift to dynamically dispatch accesses to the properties via getters and setters rather than directly accessing the member at compile time. The `dynamic` modifier comes with a significant limitation: it is only supported for types that can be represented in Objective-C. This is because Swift's dynamic dispatch is built on top of the Objective-C runtime. It is this limitation that prevents Realm from intercepting assignments to `List<T>` properties.