# Update variables in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, object, realm

This is my class:

```
class realmTickets: Object {
    dynamic var TicketPrices = 0
}

class realmXP: Object {
    dynamic var XP = 0
}

class dataReference: Object {
    var dataRefVersion = 0.0
    var xpTable = List<realmXP>()
    var ticketPricesTable = List<realmTickets>()
}
```

How do I update dataRefVersion?

I tried:

```
  currentDataReference.dataRefVersion = newestDataRef
  try! self.realm.write {
  self.realm.add(currentDataReference, update: true)
  currentDataReference.dataRefVersion = newestDataRef
 }
```

Where newestDataRef is 1.0

This is how currentDataReference is made:

```
let dataRef = self.realm.objects(dataReference)
currentDataReference = dataRef.first!
```

There is only 1 object in realm.objects.

When reloading the object, it is always set to 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties of built-in types (strings, integers, etc.) must be declared with the `dynamic` modifier to make it possible for Realm Swift to provide getters that retrieve values from the underlying Realm file. Without the `dynamic` modifier, the Swift compiler generates access to the underlying instance variable, which does not contain any data for objects loaded from a Realm file.

In addition, your two `List<T>` properties should really be declared with `let`. See [Why does Realm suggest that List<T> properties be declared using "let"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962926/why-does-realm-suggest-that-listt-properties-be-declared-using-let) for an explanation.